# Upload image to firestore using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to upload an image to firestore storage via using Laravel and i am getting an error:

This is my code:

```
     $bucketName = 'my-bucket';
     $objectName = $request->file('banner'); //Image
     $source = $request->file('banner')->move(public_path('/public/firebase-temp-uploads'));
     //return dd($source);
    $storage = new StorageClient();
    $file = fopen($source, 'r');
    $bucket = $storage->bucket($bucketName);
    $object = $bucket->upload($file, [
        'name' => $objectName
    ]);
    printf('Uploaded %s to gs://%s/%s' . PHP_EOL, basename($source), $bucketName, $objectName);
```

I have followed the documentation and still getting this error
:

> { "error": { "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials", "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid Credentials", "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ] } }

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check in the config/filesystems.php if you have the correct credentials set

Comment: Where are you running this code? What type of authorization are you using? Edit your question with details.

Comment: i am running on localhost... but i managed to resolve the issue... again thank you for your assistance. @MátyásGrőger thanks i was able to find a work around.

Comment: FYI: **localhost** is not a computer or a compute service. **localhost** is a hostname. What was the solution to your problem?

Comment: @John i was referencing the wrong JSON file for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by KgosiE, the error was due to the wrong reference of the JSON file for credentials and it is resolved now.
Anyone experiencing this issue first try to check config/filesystems.php if you have the correct credentials set or not as said by Mátyás Grőger.

For more information, you can refer to the [Article](https://laravelwithfirebase.blogspot.com/2020/07/chapter-19-how-to-upload-image-to-firebase-storage-from-laravel-php.html) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DV4YICpZ5FE) on How to upload an image to Firebase Storage from Laravel PHP project and
the [Public Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) on how to upload files with cloud storage on the web.

Comment: @KgosiE Posted an answer, is it helpful?